# How can I count specific word using mapreduce?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

I am modifying normal word count program which counts every word to make it count only specific words.

The reducer and map class are same as of normal word count. Not getting word count properly. I have multiple occurrences of same specific word in file but getting one as the count.

```
public class wordcountmapper extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<LongWritable, Tex, Text, IntWritable>                       // mapper function implemented.
{
    private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1); // intwritable
    private Text word = new Text();

    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
        String line = value.toString();      // conversion in string
        StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line);
        while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
            word.set(tokenizer.nextToken());
            if (line.compareTo("Cold") == 0) {  //cold is the specific word to get count for
                output.collect(word, one);      // getting 1 as a count for 'cold' as if its counting only first line 'cold' and not going to next line.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So what problem you are facing?

Comment: I am not getting the count of every "cold" in my file. I am just getting one as a count. Is there any problem in how i a using the if statement. @VigneshI

Comment: Is the number of reducers set to 1? And do u sum up the values coming from map side in the reducer side. Also try debugging by placing a sysout after the ouput.collect and just check how many times the key is written to the collector.

Comment: Number of reducers is 1. And i do sum up the values coming from map side. I checked by putting sysout after output.collect and collector is getting correct number of count but HDFS: Number of bytes written=0 in file system counters. If i remove the if statement from mapper then the code works fine and count all the word present in file. Its something to do with my if condition which i am not doing right! @VigneshI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a start your `if statement` is comparing the line object with "Cold" which is wrong. It should be comparing the tokenized word with "Cold" `if(tokenizer.nextToken().equals("Cold"))`.

I am not sure how with the current logic you are getting the count of "Cold" as 1. May be in your input you have a line with a single word as "Cold".